# What is the energy efficiency between FM radio tower broadcasting over an area vs point to point streaming via Internet?

Tags: energy, efficiency, frequency-modulation

Doing some research, it seems that an FM radio tower in a densely popoulated area can maximally transmit about [50kW of power](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_radiated_power).  If you assume a certain amount of people tuning into the station, is that more efficient than the same amount of people streaming the radio over the internet?

Multicast over internet is probably more efficient, but I'm not sure if most internet streaming of radio is done through multicast.

Comment: Well, you are associating power with cost. There is significant power cost with internet, but a large part of that is also paying for cable, which only sends power(mostly) where you want it.

Comment: Right.  One thing I always wondered is how much power does it take to send a packet of data over the internet?  Is there some value like average watts per kilometer per megabyte?

Comment: Multicast on the internet is barely if 'at all' used. This has to do with the fact that it needs some sort of extra administration in routing => extra servers, complex routing, ... Multicasting on a corporate LAN is more viable.

Comment: You reminded me of one of the problems we had to solve in Computer Science school.  The St. Bernard can carry 10 floppy disks of 4096K each.  A modem can transmit at 1200 baud (well, bits per second - 10 bits per character, including parity).  The dog can walk at 2 miles per hour.  How far out would the dog beat the modem in data delivery?

Comment: @Taylor, you can do a Google search to find out how many Watts it takes to process a Bitcoin transaction.  It is quite a bit.  Here is one answer:  https://motherboard.vice.com/en_us/article/bitcoin-is-unsustainable - "The energy cost of a single Bitcoin transaction could power 1.5 American homes for a day."

Answer (score 5):

This is a difficult one to answer with any amount of certainty.  But here is a way to very roughly approximate things:

First, go to [HERE](http://www.fcc.gov/encyclopedia/fm-query-broadcast-station-search) and look up a radio station.  I looked up KALC, which serves the Metro Denver area with a 100KW FM transmitter and is one of the bigger radio stations.

Next, I looked up [Denver on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denver) and found that the population of the Metro Denver area is 2.6 million people.  That works out to 38 mW of RF power per person.

Of course not all 2.6 million people in Denver are actually listening, all of the time.  And here is where it gets tricky.  We must estimate the actual number of people listening (averaged out to some time period).  This turns out to be fairly difficult for someone without access to the [Nielson ratings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nielsen_ratings).  (I should point out that Nielson does both TV and Radio ratings, but the rating system differs.)

But let's take a stab at figuring out the percentage of the population that, over a 24 hour average, is listening to that station.  There are 2.6 million people times 24 hours in a day.  That's 64.4 million people-hours of potential listeners.  If our listener utilization were 100%, that means that all 2.6 million people are listening for 24 hours in a day.  I might only listen to the radio for 1 hour/day-- 30 minutes driving to work and another 30  minutes driving home.  This means that I only contribute 4.2% to the number (1/24th).  If everyone in Denver listened for 1 hour/day then the average percentage for the entire population would be 4.2%.

Of course, not everyone listens to that station.  It is a fairly popular station, but not that many people listen to the radio and there are a lot of radio stations in Denver.  I will guess that maybe 3% of the Denver population actually listen to that station.  So 3% of 4.2% is 0.125%.  So of 64.4 million potential people-hours only 0.125%, or 0.078 million people-hours is actually utilized in our very loose estimate.

That station broadcasts at 100KW, and over a 24 hour period uses 2.4 million watt-hours.  Divide the two and you get approximately 31 watts-hours per person-hours.  Yes, this is super rough and full of errors.  But it is a reasonable approximation for our purposes.  I will address the potential errors in a moment.

Estimating the power required by an internet user is much harder to figure out.  For starters, people probably stream Pandora or Spotify much more than they listen to FM radio.  Normal radios these days is rare, while almost everyone has a computer, tablet, or phone that can stream internet radio.  Further, people will tend to not stream internet radio while in the car (except for those of us that still have unlimited data plans).

Another thing that makes it difficult to estimate is the variety of devices that people use to stream the internet.  On the power efficient end of the spectrum is the iPod Touch which might only consume 0.5 watts.  On the other end is an old PC with a CRT monitor that could be 500+ watts.  The WiFi router, Ethernet Switch, and DSL Modem (or whatever) probably contributes another 15 watts (less if those devices are shared with other users).

I am completely ignoring the power required by the Internet infrastructure that is outside of your home or office.  This is fairly small because it can be efficiently shared between homes and other businesses.  I would guess that the per internet subscriber power requirements is less than 10 watts and possibly as low as 1 watt.

So now let's address the errors in my numbers.  For the internet solution is somewhere between 15 watts and 500 watts.  Our radio solution is around 31 watts, but has a wide error margin.  The actual range might be 1/10th to 10x (or worse!).  So 3 watts to 300 watts!  While that is lower than 15-500 watts, there is such a huge error that we can only say that they are roughly comparable-- **we cannot say if one is definitively more power efficient than the other.**

Indeed, we can easily come up with scenarios where either Internet or Radio is is more efficient.  Further, the balance of power (hah hah, I crack myself up) is always shifting because the efficiency of radio changes greatly depending on how many listeners there are.  Better efficiency during rush how, and terrible efficiency at night.

Comment: Another thing to consider is that the internet infrastructure is probably powered on whether in use or not.  The router and switch in your house don't take more power as they handle more packets (mostly).

Comment: While for the internet infrastructure in your house (or even in your street) this may be true, it will not be the case for the "true" internet infrastructure. Capacity is only added when it is really needed. Without media streaming there would certainly be less internet infrastructure in existence. - Though admittedly, the energy cost of the internet infrastructure was ignored in the answer, so the comment would be true in this limited context.

Comment: I really enjoyed the answer!  I figure both were somewhat comparable re: power usage or else radio stations wouldn't really offer it as an option.  The reason I asked this is because I listen to KQED here in Silicon Valley at work.  I wish I could use a normal radio, but the signal doesn't reach deep inside the building, where I sit.  So, I have to stream it through my smartphone.

Comment: The internet is not dedicated to any one area. You want to compare this to the internet coverage of Denver alone and I'd bet the total power used is less than a 100w light bulb for a week.

Comment: You did not take into account that the 100KW is ERP and the antenna they are using is a 6 bay rototiller with a gain of 6db. That means that assuming minimal transmission line loss they are only putting 25KW "up the pipe" from the transmitter. Your calculations are off by a factor of almost 4x.